# Java UDF same as User Defined Method?

Tags: java

Is User Defined Function same as User Defined Method? Because I do know that Function is the same as a method. It's just confusing me a bit and want to confirm that I am indeed correct.

Also extra question is to create a UDF all you have to do is create a method/function inside the class right? Or do you have to create a new CLASS for each UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is User Defined Function same as User Defined Method?

Generally, yes.

In languages like C++, functions are defined outside of classes. In contrast, in Java, methods are part of a class. Java does not allow you to define functions outside of classes (but you can make functions `static`, which removes the need for an *instance*; these are usually called "static" or "[class methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2)" in Java). Yes, you can create as many methods as you like inside a `class`.

Comment: Like that's how you do UDF right? Or am I doing the wrong thing?

Comment: They certainly appear to be user defined functions.

Comment: Alright thanks again. Sorry if I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be. So in short 'User Defined Functions' is pretty much self explanatory. So UDF => Functions created by the user. Alright I'll keep that in mind next time. =)